# How to post data via form HTML?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, http-post

I want to post the data to the server via form. How can I do this?

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <form role="form" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sender-email" class="control-label">Username:</label>
            <div class="input-icon"> <i class="icon-user fa"></i>
                <input id="sender-email" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-pass" class="control-label">Password:</label>
            <div class="input-icon"> <i class="icon-lock fa"></i>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="user-pass">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="authenticate_user" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**My views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST.get('sender-email') #prints None
        username = request.POST['username'] # throws error, username not available.
        password = request.POST['password']
```

How do I post the data without using jquery? I know of a way of posting through AJAX jquery, but dont wanna do that.

Comment: Why do you use {% csrf_token %} in your template and @csrf_exempt in your view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'name'` attribute of input tags is set as keys of `request.GET` and `request.POST`.

Add name attribute to all your input tags.

```
<input name="username" id="sender-email" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control email">

<input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="user-pass" >
```

Comment: "Django uses the 'name' attribute of input tags as keys of request.GET and request.POST" : this is nothing Django-specific, it's the HTML spec.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes I'm aware of that. But stating a specific case doesn't mean the generic is otherwise. I understand, though that it might create confusion/ impart half knowledge. Hence edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

POST data are populated using the `name` attribute of your input elements. Change your `id` attributes or add a `name` one accordingly. E.g:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="user-pass">
```

You should also consider using a [form](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html) to handle your data more easily.